# Why list of WebElements in Selenium becomes empty after driver.get("URL")?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I faced a strange problem. This code is working properly.
It prints all hyperlinks that present on the page.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import java.util.List;
    public class MyMain {
        public static WebDriver driver;
        public static List<WebElement> aList;//the list of all elements with tag <a>
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications"); //disable popup alerts from chrome
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            int counter = 0; // number of elements in aList just for debug
            String hrefAttribute = "";
            driver.get("https://www.zap.co.il/");
            aList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.println(aList.size());//just for debug
            for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i ++ ) {
            hrefAttribute = aList.get(i).getAttribute("href");
             if (hrefAttribute != null) {             
                        System.out.println(hrefAttribute);
                        counter +=1;                  
                }
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
```

But if I want to navigate to all of the links ( or even one of them), I face the issue, where after "driver.get(hrefAttribute);" and "driver.get("https://www.zap.co.il/");" the list of WebElements becomes empty (it stay the same size of 162 elements).

```
   

     if (hrefAttribute != null) {
               driver.get(hrefAttribute);
                    System.out.println(hrefAttribute);
                    counter +=1;
                    driver.get("https://www.zap.co.il/"); //here the list becomes empty!!!                 
            }
```

I fixed the issue by adding:

```
   

    if (hrefAttribute != null) {
               driver.get(hrefAttribute);
                    System.out.println(hrefAttribute);
                    counter +=1;
                    driver.get("https://www.zap.co.il/"); //here the list becomes empty!!!  
                    aList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));//this fixed the issue.But WHY?
            }
```

I will really appreciate it if anyone can explain this strange behavior to me.

Answer (score 1):

> the list of WebElements becomes empty (it stay the same size of 162
> elements)

I question whether the list actually becomes "empty"; in fact you say yourself that it still contains 162 elements. I suspect your WebElements become "stale" (at least that's what would happen in C#, which is what I use).

WebElement objects are connected to the live loaded page in the browser, so when you load a different page, all existing WebElement objects go "stale"; they're no longer connected to an actual HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw Stale Element Reference Exception .As your DOM will reload ?
or does it simply does not enters the loop.

The second line which you say fixes the issue is because it fetches all the elements with tag a again.